# How to activate Python virtualenvironment not knowing the terminal

Tags: python, makefile, terminal, virtualenv

I need to activate Python's virtual environment from inside Makefile.

Python `venv` module creates virtual environment with activation files for 3 different terminals:

- activate
- activate.bat
- Activate.ps1

is it possible to activate virtual environment from inside the Makefile, not knowing from what type of terminal (CMD, PowerShell, bash) the person will run a Makefile command?

Comment: You could call the Python binary directly: `<your_venv_directory>/Scripts/python`, not really a need to activate.

Comment: That's probably a better solution anyway, as activation only applies to a single shell session and most Makefile recipes consist of multiple shell sessions.

Comment: That wouldn't address environment changes such as PYTHONPATH though.

Answer (score -1):

With the following commmand you can check which type of shell you are using.

```
echo $0
```

Afterwards you can simply catch the correct path by if statements.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/590899/how-do-i-check-which-shell-i-am-using